# Portable load pe from resource c++

Tags: c++, memory, resources, load

I have been trying to figure this out forever.  I need to load a PE from memory in c++ but I can't get it to work on xp/win vista/win 7/win 8 /32 bit / 64 bit.

No this is not for malicious purposes.  Does anyone know why this would only work for a certain OS if I am building a win32 console app?

What are some of the reasons that cause this?  Is there a solution?

Comment: "I can't get it to work" - I'm afraid you're going to have to elaborate *considerably* on that premise. *What* doesn't seem to be working? *How* are you currently trying to load the PE image? *Which* platform SDK are you using, and is it compatible with the platform(s) you're running on? etc. *Post your failing code*, along with your assessment of where the wheels come off and your suspicions for why.

Comment: My code is so mutilated right now I will have to update it in a little while and post it.  I am using Visual studio default settings but I have tried changing it to target windows xp, 110, 120..  I have no idea what the problem is.